# Need to learn more about Precision and Accuracy

Tags: references, query, accuracy, precision

I am currently taking Introduction to Image Interpretation online and there is a section in it that talks about Precision and Accuracy. I wanted to know if someone out there has any good information that I can use to learn more about it.

Comment: Is the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) on the subject not enough?

Comment: About three dozen threads on our site provide discussions of precision and accuracy in GIS applications.  Use a [search](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bprecision%20%2baccuracy) to find them.  (Be a little careful, though: not everyone uses these two words correctly!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Dartboard Precision vs. Accuracy]

This illustration stuck with me, and helps me remember at the most basic level what precision vs. accuracy is.[This is the source of the image, also containing a little more context.](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/3310/3390101/blb0105.html) In general, **Precision** is the how close your grouping of measurements are. **Accuracy** is how close your measurement is to the actual measurement in the real world.

Blah238 is right, they left out **Accurate, but not Precise**  - that might look something like:
[image]

Comment: They forgot "good accuracy; poor precision" :) I guess you can't have good accuracy without good precision.

Comment: Nice catch! I added a poorly GIMP'ed image to illustrate that situation.

Comment: Nice one, thanks :) It's also noted in the Wikipedia article: [Image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/High_accuracy_Low_precision.svg/300px-High_accuracy_Low_precision.svg.png)

Comment: Actually, the third image on the right illustrates *good* accuracy and low precision, because the centroid of the three darts is close to the center of the board.  A correct illustration of poor accuracy and poor precision would show the dots widely scattered around a point far from the bull's-eye (e.g., they might be scattered around a point not even on the dartboard).  A better source for these illustrations appears on our sister site, [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17545)